# Migrating to Android Studio

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I want to migrate from Eclipse to Android Studio, but unfortunately Eclipse was crashed so I couldn't build gradle-build files, so I reinstalled Eclipse, and luckily I still had those, I copied my old files which where in my old workspace (the workspace from before the crash) to a new workspace.

But, when I build the gradle-build files now and I import them in Android Studio it says my gridlayout_v7 is missing.

Does anyone of you know how I can solve this?

Comment: do you have any working solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Run SDK Manager and check that you have installed:

- Android Support Repository
- Android Support Library
- Google Repository

Then check if your `build.gradle` has next lines:

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:18.0.0'
}
```

You dont need separate gridlayout library subproject anymore with new build system.